# "ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE" - when does it gets fired, and what are the consequences?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

### Background

The documentation of the "[**ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE)" intent action says:

> Broadcast Action: Resources for a set of packages are currently
>   unavailable since the media on which they exist is unavailable. The
>   extra data EXTRA_CHANGED_PACKAGE_LIST contains a list of packages
>   whose availability changed. The extra data EXTRA_CHANGED_UID_LIST
>   contains a list of uids of packages whose availability changed. The
>   specified set of packages can no longer be launched and are
>   practically unavailable on the system.

### The problem

I can't find enough information about this kind of intent, and what information will be unavailable about the apps.

My guess is that it only applies to SD-card, and that all is available except the data that is store in the SD-card, which is only cache and OBB files, and files that the app has created.

However, I remember that it's possible to move apps to the SD-card, which I'm not sure what it means about other kinds of information (even basic ones), and if moving apps to the SD-card also include the APK file.

### The questions

Say the list of packages that are inside the intent (which you get from "EXTRA_CHANGED_PACKAGE_LIST") called "listed-apps" .

1. When does this intent get fired? Does it have anything to do with SD-Card being removed from its slot (or unmounted by the device) ?
2. What kind of information would be missing/unavailable about each of the "listed-apps" ?
3. What kind of information would still be available about each of the "listed-apps" ?
4. Would using any of the [**PackageManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)'s features be affected in any way on each of the "listed-apps" ? Would getting the apps' names and icons still be available?